# How do I enable more handshake ciphers in CFStream?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, ssl, cfreadstream

When running the method:

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty(theReadStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings (CFDictionaryRef)tlsPacket->tlsSettings);
```

To secure the connection of a CFReadStream, my iphone client returns the error:

```
Error Domain=kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL Code=-9824 "Operation could not be completed. (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9824.)"
```

and the server sends the error:

```
ERROR [STDERR] javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

Is there any way to allow CFReadStream to use additional ciphers during the handshake process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem:

It turns out that the problem was on the server side.  If you run into this issue yourself I would urge you to check that the handshake on the server side is working properly.